# Need to bypass WCF decryption of response message

Tags: java, wcf, encryption, vb.net-2010

I am connecting to a java web service that uses an additional secret key in it's response. My client is written in vb.net (VS 2010, .net 4.0). This secret key is encrypted with my public key and is used to encrypt the response message. As a result, when I send my client request to this service I get the following error in the response: "The incoming message was signed with a token which was different from what used to encrypt the body.  This was not expected." In an attempt to resolve this error I created a custom message encoder to intercept the response message, get the secret key and decrypt it using my private key, and then use that key to decrypt the response message. I have successfully decrypted the message and have modified the response message with the decrypted message and returned that message to the custom message encoder ReadMessage method, where it creates the message that is returned to WCF for processing. However, even with that decrypted return message I still get the same error: "The incoming message was signed with a token which was different from what used to encrypt the body.  This was not expected." It appears WCF is still attempting to decrypt the message even after I have done that manually. I have spent many hours on this issue and am trying to determine how to bypass the default WCF decryption process and let it use my custom decrypted message. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using one of ReadMessage overloads inside custom encoder, for example

`public override Message ReadMessage(ArraySegment<byte> buffer, BufferManager bufferManager, string contentType)`

and you return decrypted message in an expected format, for example you re-create it using

`return Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Soap11, String.Empty, XElement.Parse(plainTextData));`

you should set `AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement.EnableUnsecuredResponse` to true, it is used exactly to allow encrypted request and decrypted (plaint text) response, important thing is there are no security headers in a returned response (which is how the new response is created in a code example above).